# How to change the post type a theme shows by default?

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, theme-development, filters

I have a theme that displays the normal post_type `post`, but want it to take the post from my custom post type `my_posts_custom`.

I don't want to make this change manually on the theme. Are there any filters that I can use and change the `post_type` the theme will handle or  display by default?

Comment: Yes you can use custom post type data as well , but why you want to change post type using filter. You can use wp_query as well to show custom post type data.

Comment: It's possible, however, instead of adjusting the theme to display a `custom_post_type` in place of `post`, why not use the default post type `post` for your purpose? If you need different attributes for `post`, you can extend `post` attributes the same way you've created the custom post type.